# Is it true that the keyboards for laptops are not sold separately?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Like what I'm trying to find is that keyboard of my laptop (Acer aspire 4937g) the exact same size with the distance between all the keys all the same and no single extra key or less key. I've visited like 50 shops but they all do not sell that.

**i don't want laptop parts that I can fix into my laptop, no!**

I do not want a replacement keyboard. I want an external keyboard which is an exact twin of the keyboard i had stuck to my laptop (i.e. all the keys are the same) that I can connect to my laptop (through USB or the like)

Is it true that the keyboards for laptops are not sold separately?

(the current answer with 11 votes seems to be off-topic, neither are the other 5 answers answering the question)